# Update a list in another list using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a list property, called Fruits with some elements inside. The whole list is binded to a Combobox, which displays it. I also create a field and a property called CurrentFruit to get and set the SelectedItem and I bind it to a Textbox, in order to see the update. Now I am trying to do something similar for the property UpdatedFruits, the only thing that is different is that this List depends on the SelectedItem from the Fruits list. That is when I select and item from the Combobox1, e.g. "Orange", and then you open up the Combobox2, it should appear only the string "Apple". I have tried to remove it directly in the getter of the UpdatedFruits list, but it only displays the whole list again. That may be, because in the constructor I assign the value of UpdatedFruits equals Fruits.

**xaml.cs**

```
public class NewLUT_ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Fruits { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
        "Orange",
        "Apple",
        "Banana"
    };

    public NewLUT_ViewModel()
    {
        UpdatedFruits = Fruits;
    }

    private string currentFruit;
    public string CurrentFruit
    {
        get
        {
            return currentFruit;
        }
        set
        {
            currentFruit = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> updatedFruits;
    public ObservableCollection<string> UpdatedFruits
    {
        get
        {
            return updatedFruits;
        }
        set
        {
            Fruits.Remove(CurrentFruit);
            updatedFruits = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

**xaml**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentFruit}"/>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UpdatedFruits}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentFruit}"></TextBox>
```

Comment: Use ObservableCollection

Comment: of course list would behave that way, list doesn't notify the changes from "its elements"

Comment: @Babbillumpa for both lists?

Comment: Yes. Note that if you remove the element from Fruits, even the first combo will lose the element...if i were in you, i would change strategy...

Comment: @RendonLs Do u want remove items that is selected in Fruits combobox from UpdatedFruits combobox? I believe the item selected in Fruits combobox should be enabled or disabled accordingly in Updated combobox. Check out the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62152705/10024696) if this is the case